Why does a pick between HDD and SSD matter when synchronizing cryptocurrency over the internet?
I'm a monero enthusiast that wants to run his own node to support the monero network. This question might seem trivial or maybe even stupid, but I'll try my luck here nonetheless.
As a system administrator, it's always been my belief that internet ADSL speeds are slower than storage write speeds.
However, despite this knowledge, I see online many users that claim that, if you plan on starting to run your own node, it's better to pick an SSD as the storage medium for the blockchain rather than a HDD, as the write speeds of an SSD are higher than those of an HDD.
While I know the fact that SSD write speeds are indeed way higher than HDD write speeds, from my understanding, when downloading a full blockchain for the first time, the bottleneck for why it takes so long is not the write speed of the medium the blockchain is written to, but the internet speeds at which the data is downloaded from.
As such, there should, in theory, be no distinction as to whether an HDD or an SSD is used, as the bottleneck would be the internet that data is coming from.
Or, to get into even more detail, my understanding is that the buffer that data is written from onto the storage is somewhere in RAM and has a dynamic size. New blockchain data comes from the network card, since the blockchain is downloaded from some peers over the internet, and that gets added to this RAM buffer, while old data is constantly being written to the storage from this buffer sequentially. Given the fact that, I assume, the download speed of the ADSL network is slower than the write speeds of a conventional HDD or SSD, eventually this would lead to an imbalance that would cause the buffer to eventually be fully written since the data coming from the network to the storage medium runs out since it's being written faster than it comes in. The process will then have to wait for new data to come in from the internet to continue writing. Effectively, the slow internet speeds would be the reason why everything stalls.
The only way I see that the difference in writing speeds between HDDs and SSDs would come into play is if this was false and the internet speed was higher than an HDD's write speeds, in which case the imbalance would tip into the other direction. But that goes against everything I know about hardware.
Are my assumptions incorrect and, if so, can you please explain how?
To make this question clearer and easier to answer, assume the internet connection is through a standard Ethernet cable (I don't want to get into the logistics of why wireless internet is inherently slower than Ethernet cable internet. That's not the point of this post)

Profile your application and figure out what resource is bottlenecking it.

It seems to me that you are assuming writing the blockchain will be an uninterrupted linear process. Why do you make that assumption? A blockchain will be retrieved from its peers in pieces that are not by any means linear; you'll be receiving current blocks at the same time you are backfilling historical blocks, and the historical blocks will, at least for the first while, be randomly scattered throughout your notional buffer. If you wait for contiguous buffer sections to be completed before writing them, you could be waiting a long time and tying up an arbitrarily large block of memory. Typically blockchain retrieval will use smaller buffers, and write them to disk as they are verified. At least for the initial blockchain creation, you'll be writing random blocks, and small-block random write speed will control your performance. Receiving a new block also requires committing it to disk, which requires writing to the blockchain file, writing to its journal twice, and writing to the directory, which if it's frequent enough will also be impacted by the same random write speed spec. Plus there are concerns about what other workload your system will be dealing with. Providing blockchain information to peers will require random seeks and reading as well, so the fact that an SSD's read speed is so much higher than spinning rust will also prove to be a performance factor. Basically, this is a disk-intensive process, no matter how it's sliced, and so disk speed, whether read or write, will eventually rule.
